# subscribing to mailchimp from my site's signup form

Tags: forms, email, registration, newsletter, mailchimp

I'm working on a website, it has membership. visitor fills form and be member. now somehow I need to forward the email at this signup form to my mailchimp mail list, so from 1 form I will get membership (to my site's db) and added email to mailchimp (for newsletter)

is it possible?

appreciate advises!! thanks!

Comment: Why don't you simply export the list from your DB in CSV/Excel format and import it Mailchimp. Importing CSV/Excel list is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible through Mailchimp's API. You'll need to know programming to do this but I assume since you're on StackOverflow you can handle it. :)

http://apidocs.mailchimp.com

Basically what I do is handle the form registration logic on my application, then send the user's email address and other information through the Mailchimp API's listSubscribe() method to add that user to my mailing list.

http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/1.3/listsubscribe.func.php

Hope that helps!